# How to share data between different stages of CompletableFuture in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I am working on a code that deals with CompletableFuture. It looks something like shown below. Is it possible to share data between stages of computing a completableFuture in Java. I think one way of sharing is through using AtomicReference on the ID and updating / accessing it where needed, but I am not sure if that is the right way. Please guide me on this.

```
CompletableFuture<Response> serverResponseCf = service.get("someKey");
    serverResponseCf.thenApplyAsync(
      response -> {
        String id = response.getId();
        return retrieveDifferentObject(id);
      }
    ).thenAcceptAsync(
       thatDiffObject -> {
         /* Here I need the ID also, that was retrieved in previous stage. */
       }
    ).
... chain goes on
.
```

Comment: Are you using Java 16 or newer?

Comment: I am on Java 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HomeworkHopper was implying, if you are using Java 16 or newer, the standard solution is to use a [`Java Record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html). (that link is for the latest version, Java 20 -- strive to use the latest version when possible)

You can then do something like this.

```java
    class Response {final int id; /* constructors and stuff here. */}
    
    record BundledResponse (Response response, SomeOtherData etc) {}
```

Which enables you to do something like this. I have added types to properly communicate what is happening.

```java
CompletableFuture<Response> serverResponseCf = service.get("someKey");
    serverResponseCf.thenApplyAsync(
      Response response -> {
        String id = response.getId();
        return retrieveDifferentObject(id);
      }
    ).thenAcceptAsync(
       BundledResponse thatDiffObject -> {
         /* Here I need the ID also, that was retrieved in previous stage. */
       }
    ).
... chain goes on
```

This way, you can get both the new data you need AND the id you passed in. There are a couple of ways to do it, but this is pretty much the first thing Java developers reach for nowadays.

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer. This looks clean and seems to be same as returning a bean with actual response and the ID. Is there any other way,  where I might need to access a variable that was computed / generated two or three stages above the current one ? and I dont want to bundle it into every stage. Instead save it somewhere outside of the CompletableFuture chaining and accessible from any block of the chain. Just thinking if something like that is available, would be cleaner ?

Comment: @Abhi.P Each CompletionStage of a CompletableFuture chain is really supposed to be stateless. That's why the API was designed to facilitate data flow by passing the return value of the previous stage as input to the next. Mutating an external variable from within any lambda expression is difficult, and requires a hacky workaround such as an AtomicReference or one-element array, because lambdas aren't meant to mutate external state. Ideally, each CompletionStage, as well as the entire CompletableFuture chain, should be a "black box" which performs a task and yields a value when it's finished.

Comment: @Abhi.P HomeworkHopper answered correctly. Unfortunately, I can't think of anything besides bundling it all. Maybe there is some creative way to get there though.

Comment: That’s one of the issues Virtual Threads solve. Then, you can simply write a sequential piece of code holding all values in ordinary local variables, as many as needed, and simply calling `join()` on each future before proceeding to the next stage. Then, each stage can access all variables defined at this point.

Comment: @Holger Very true. I don't have time to make an answer for this, but really, writing the code sequentially is the way to do it. Then just toss it into a thread per request